# Conditional(?) functions and uniform continuity

Tags: calculus

Let the function $f(x)$ be defined as $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
    -x,& \text{if } -1 \le x <  0\\
    x^2,              & \text{if } 0 \le x \le 1  
\end{cases}$$

If I wish to show that the function is uniform continuous on the interval $[-1, 1]$, what is sufficient to show? We have that continuity does not imply uniform continuity. However, we do have that the function is continuous at $0$, and most problems with uniform continuity for continuous functions happen when working with functions approaching infinite values ($x^2, \frac{1}{x}$ etc). Is it sufficient to show that $-x$ is uniformly continuous on $[-1, 0]$ and $x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, 1]$, or do I have to find an expression that holds for both functions in their respective intervals?

Seeing as some answers have used the compact sets, Heine theorem etc, I should note we are to show it using the definition of uniform continuity. We have not been through more than the definition itself and a few simple examples.

Comment: Do you know the [Heine theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem)?

Comment: No, I do not. (We have not been through it in class, either, so one can solve the task without it.) We are also to solve the task "from its respective definition", and I doubt this would be a valid answer.

Comment: Intuitively, this function has a graph that never increases "steeper" than a slope of $2$, so for given $\epsilon > 0$, even if the $x$ values are not known yet, it should be OK to choose $\delta = \epsilon/2$ and use that in the definition of uniform continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the [Heine theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem):

- let us show that $$
  x\in[-1,0]\to -x\\ x\in[0,1] \to x^2
  $$
  are both uniformly continuous.
  For the first one, just take $\delta = \epsilon$ in the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Local_continuity_versus_global_uniform_continuity).
  For the second one, $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)\leq 2(x-y)$ so just take $\delta = \frac 12\epsilon$ in the definition.
- Now, consider $x,y\in[-1,1]$. If they are in the same interval $[0,1]$ or $[-1,0]$ then you are done.
  Otherwise, assume $x<0<y$, and $|x-y|\leq \delta =\frac 13 \epsilon$.
  $$
  |f(y) - f(x)| \leq  |f(y) - f(0)|  + |f(x) - f(0)| \leq \delta + 2\delta = \epsilon
  $$
  because $|x-0|\leq \delta$ and $|y-0|\leq \delta$ and the first part.

Answer (score 1):

"We have that continuity does not imply uniform continuity"

It does on a compact set, which $[-1,1]$ is. Therefore, it is enough to show that the function is continuous on $[-1,1]$. It is obvious that it is continuous for any point $a\in[-1,1]\setminus \{0\}$. All you have to show is that it is continuous at $0$, which is not hard to do.

Comment: Well, after a short Wikipedia-visit, I have no doubt that your answer is correct. However, we are asked to show it from the definition of uniform continuity. The argument using the Heine theorem is something we have yet to touch.